# Count the datarow from datatable[]

Tags: c#

I had 1 dataset and 4 datables.
So how to count the each row of those data tables?

```
DataTable[] ret = 
{
    new DataTable(), 
    new DataTable(), 
    new DataTable(), 
    new DataTable()
};

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Delivery Date", typeof (string));
    table.Columns.Add("Ord.Qty", typeof (string));
    table.Columns.Add("Balance", typeof (string));
    ret[i] = table;
}
```

this 1 is calculate the total row of 4 datatables.

```
int rowCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the Row Count of every table seperately into an Array of integers use -

```
 var count = ret.Select(table => table.Rows.Count);
```

To get the total number of rows in all the tables use -

```
 var sumOfRowCount = ret.Select(table => table.Rows.Count).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark here...

```
var count = 0;

foreach (var t in ds.Tables)
{
    count += t.Rows.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May this work to you -

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // just add your tables in this **ds**.

    int totalRows = 0;

    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            totalRows++;
    }

    Response.Write(totalRows.ToString());
```